# UK Fiance visa: Does my American Master's degree need to be recognized by UK NARIC?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, uk-visa, family

I am applying for the Fiance visa in the UK and I need to prove my knowledge of English. I'm originally from Brazil which means my native language is Portuguese, however, I have a MFA degree from an American University in the United States, having lived there for a few years.

Does the degree still need to be recognized by UK NARIC when it's obvious that it was taught in English? Or is the degree itself enough proof?

Answer (score 2):

No, the degree in itself is not sufficient. The guidance states that you can prove your knowledge of English if BOTH (emphasis added):

- you have a degree or academic qualification that was taught or researched in English
- your qualification is recognised by UK NARIC as being equivalent to a UK bachelor’s degree or higher

https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/knowledge-of-english